# How to make mosaic automatically from quadrocopter photos?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have many aerial photos (not georeferenced) from a quadrocopter and I want to make a mosaic from them, but it takes so much time.

Could you help me with this problem or give me advice on programs which can do this operation automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to stitch together photos you could use a variety of software, such as [Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/photoshop.html) (Photomerge function), [Photosynth](https://www.photosynth.net/) or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) (with the Stitch Panorama plugin) as a free alternative.

If you want to use photogrammetry software and have the option to create a 3D mesh, DSM etc, then there are several options, including [Agisoft Photoscan](http://www.agisoft.com/), [Pix4D](https://pix4d.com/), or [VisualSFM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/) (free for non-commercial use).

Depending on the number and the quality of the photos, and computing power available, creating orthomosaics (and especially photogrammetric 3D models), by its very nature always takes time...

Comment: OK, could you tell me which of all those programs merge photos without coordinates (latitude and longitude  ).

Comment: As photoshop, It does not save inpute sizes of images

Comment: @ЄвгенШмиголь, sorry, not sure whether you're after georeferenced imagery or just stitched-together images? Any of these programs will stitch images together, but Photoshop/Photosynth/GIMP won't georeference, they are just image editing programs. You can still manually georeference a stitched image in GIS software, but not as accurate as processing through photogrammetry software.

Comment: I want stich-together photos without georeferencing

Answer (score 0):

You can join beta test of [ESRI Drone2map](http://www.esri.com/products/drone2map) program. But you might need some metadata for automated processing your photos.

Comment: could you tell me I should download demoversion of drone to map?

Comment: and what metadata shoud have image?

Comment: @ЄвгенШмиголь For sure downloading is needed. Sorry, I can't answer your second question, please, read Drone2map manuals.

Comment: thank you, I have tryed to make It with Drone2map, but it gives me error. Probably I do it wrong I dont know. I will read manuals